# To Reuse images and text in list view when internet is not available

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask, android-lifecycle, android-memory

I have created five Horizontal ListView with images and texts in one activity. Using Lazy loading of images concept it is working fine. Now when it is offline, the list is showing blank,ie., no data . I need to implement memory-caching concept, such that when it is offline it will be showing the previous session datas(images & texts).

In oncreate:  I am calling the Asynctask. In doinbackground method of asynctask,I am consuming Webservices containing images & texts,then I am passing those datas to the adapter. And in postexecute, I am setting my adapter to Listview.

In adapter class: getview method I am setting the texts and loading the images using lazy loading.

Please help me to get rid of this. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can store the state of your data in `onPostExecute()`(meaning: successfully executed AsyncTask). Register a listener for the Network state. If and when connection drops, load data from backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store text etc. in an `SQLiteDatabase` and store your `Images` on external storage.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I am having around 20-30 items for every List. Will it be efficient then to store in SqliteDatabase and external storage.

Comment: Absolutely! It's THE way to handle that stuff! [Here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)'s a tutorial you should have a look at concerning `ListView` stuff. It's very good.